# org.springframework.data.solr.UncategorizedSolrException: Failed to convert to type org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument

Tags: solr, spring-data-jpa

I use [spring-data-solr](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-solr.git) to integrate spring-data-jpa with solr, but when i use SolrOperations to saveBean(org.domain.Article), an exception throws:

org.springframework.data.solr.UncategorizedSolrException: Failed to convert from type org.kb.domain.Article to type org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument for value 'Article [id=1,title=test-1, description=test-1, content=test-1, author=test-1, link=test-1, attachment=test-1, date=Sat Jan 05 20:06:12 CST 2013, category=org.kb.domain.Category@67e6cf07]'; nested exception is org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.BindingException: Invalid setter method. Must have one and only one parameter; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type org.kb.domain.Article to type org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument for value 'Article [id=1,title=test-1, description=test-1, content=test-1, author=test-1, link=test-1, attachment=test-1, date=Sat Jan 05 20:06:12 CST 2013, category=org.kb.domain.Category@67e6cf07]'; nested exception is org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.BindingException: Invalid setter method. Must have one and only one parameter

here is my bean:

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.Field;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
@Entity
@Table(name="article")
public class Article extends IdEntity{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -5170398606065544445L;

private String title;

private String description;

private String content;

private String author;

private String link;

private String attachment;

private Date date;

private Category category;

public Article() {
    super();
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="category_id")
public Category getCategory() {
    return category;
}
public void setCategory(Category category) {
    this.category = category;
}

@Column(name="title")
@Field("title")
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

@Column(name="description")
@Field("description")
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

@Column(name="content")
@Field("content")
public String getContent() {
    return content;
}
public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

@Column(name="author")
@Field("author")
public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}
public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

@Column(name="link")
@Field("link")
public String getLink() {
    return link;
}
public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
}

@Column(name="attachment")
@Field("attachment")
public String getAttachment() {
    return attachment;
}

public void setAttachment(String attachment) {
    this.attachment = attachment;
}

@Column(name="date")
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd", timezone="GMT+08:00")
public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}
public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Article [id=" + id + ",title=" + title + ", description=" +     description
            + ", content=" + content + ", author=" + author + ", link="
            + link + ", attachment=" + attachment + ", date=" + date
            + ", category=" + category + "]";
}
```

}

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.Field;

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class IdEntity implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5676694680777491651L;
protected Long id;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Field("id")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your solrj Field annotation. Have a look at the [documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj#Directly_adding_POJOs_to_Solr):

> The @Field annotation can be applied to a field or a setter method.

You should move the Field annotation to the either the setId setter method or the id field itself. You can even remove the id qualifier since the field name is already id, that's enough:

```
@Field
protected Long id;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```